# TFS: What is "local branch" and what is "source branch" when merging

Tags: tfs, merge

I am merging a branch "B" with another branch "A" so I right-clicked in "B" in the Source Code Explorer and selected Merge, then, in the following screen, I selected branch "A". TFS nomenclature is not clear. I would think "source branch" is B and "local" branch is "A". Is it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it worded that way, I always though it was source and target.

[image: mergewizard]

B will be the source and A will be your target.

when merging, make sure you have the latest versions of source control in your workspace before you start. the merge will be done in your local workspace, and then you will comit from there to Source control. Having the latest ensures that all of the merge issues are sorted out in your local workspace before you push back to TFS